# Is there a way to avoid from entering the localhost password again and again while starting and stopping hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

When I am going to start the hadoop it required to enter localhost password three times and it is same on stopping hadoop. Is there a way to avoid from entering the localhost password again and again?

Comment: Have you really tried searching for it before asking the question?This is one of the most common things which can be found on any page related to Hadoop setup, including the official document : **http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/single_node_setup.html#Setup+passphraseless**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure ssh to be able to do a passwordless ssh login.
Nothing better than a good link: http://hortonworks.com/kb/generating-ssh-keys-for-passwordless-login/

It is related to the files `~/hadoop/conf/masters`, `~/hadoop/conf/slaves` and the scripts of starting and stoping. When you run them, they connect to the hosts listed in those configuration files to run the master and slaves nodes in them.

Hope it helps :)